# How long does the Dengue virus last in the human body?

Tags: virus

As far as I understand Dengue is transmitted through mosquitos when they bite an infected human, and the new born mosquitos arent born with the virus. We are having a bad Dengue epidemy here for the first time, and word is the epidemy will reappear here next summer even if the mosquito dies in winter and new mosquitos are born in spring/summer. I can't think of another way for this to happen only than people who got the disease still carry the virus somehow. I tried to look information about this, but the only thing I found is the infection last 10-14 days, I dont know if this means the virus completely disappears or just the symptons disappear.

How long does the Dengue virus last in the human body? Will someone who recovered from Dengue be able to transmit the disease if bitten by a mosquito?

Comment: you got monkeys?

Comment: It's Argentina, no there arent monkeys around

Comment: Hard to believe there are no monkeys around in Argentina

Comment: You may not have monkeys in your neighborhood, but [there are five species](https://tropicalconservationscience.mongabay.com/content/v1/08-06-09-Zunino-Kowaleski.html) of monkeys in Argentina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These viruses sit in animal populations and are transferred to humans by mosquitoes

> Flaviviruses are responsible for a growing disease burden in Argentina and other countries in the Americas. Non-human primates, such as monkeys, can be important hosts in the natural cycle of several flaviviruses. Yellow Fever virus outbreaks occurred in Argentina during 2007–2009 in areas of Misiones and Corrientes provinces inhabited by black howlers (Alouatta caraya), a monkey that is highly susceptible to the virus. During 2010 we tested 108 black howlers from Northeastern Argentina for flaviviruses. Most of these animals were negative for Yellow Fever virus but had antibodies to several other flaviviruses. Unexpectedly, the highest specific neutralizing antibody prevalence was to West Nile Virus; these results represent the first evidence of West Nile Virus circulation in a new host in Argentina. Detection of **Dengue virus antibodies in black howlers** highlights the potential for establishment of a dengue sylvatic cycle, not yet demonstrated in the Americas. We call for strengthening the monitoring of flaviviruses to evaluate risk for wildlife and human health in the region.

https://journals.plos.org/plosntds/article?id=10.1371/journal.pntd.0005351

Comment: There are monkeys in the North, but I'm in the center of Argentina, no monkeys or primates here. Could there be other animal species which keeps the virus around?

Comment: Humans are primates

Comment: Ok, no non human primates